# Pros and cons of periodically running yourself into wall in Temple Run?

Tags: temple-run

In Temple Run if I run myself into the wall in quick succession, I will be killed by the flesh-eating monkeys. However if I space out when I run into the wall, this seems like a strategic way of slowing my character down so that I can keep running for longer without getting overwhelmed by the speed. Is this a viable strategy?

Are there other pros and cons to this strategy that I have not considered?

Comment: I've noticed sometimes that if I'm going too slow, there are some gaps that are just too long for me to jump. Maybe it's possible if you nail the jump timing, but with a bit of extra speed it becomes cake to jump it.

Answer (score 3):

A good thing about this is that it slows you down, and slower speed is easier to control. However, the bad things are that it resets your extra points with coins count up bar and  some jumps are too long if you are going too slow.